# How and why is p:inputMask submitting slotChar as value?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a web application using Primefaces 5.2, running on GlassFish 4.1, that has some elements p:inputMask like this example:

```html
<p:inputMask slotChar="_" mask="9" required="true" />
```

In the server side, I realized that sometimes the submitted value is "_" (without quotes).

I tried to reproduce the problem, but I didn't understand how this happens.
I tried leaving the field blank, copy-paste, pressing enter... I searched in internet, but only found this problem on older versions of PrimeFaces.

I can't talk with users. I just know the last one who caused this error was using Google Chrome.

Does anyone have any clue about how to reproduce the problem? I need to understand this, so I can solve the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Primefaces?  And you said its fixed on new PF versions?

Comment: I think you  best option is to add a validator. I can't reproduce it (using pf 5.2) with regular user interaction, but you can inspect the element in the browser console, then **edit it as HTML** and add a `value="_"` or  `value="any other garbage"` to the input. Then press `<ctrl>+<return>` and trigger the submit button. This will sucessfully submit and proofs client side enforcement is nice but not enough.

Comment: @Melloware I'm using PF 5.2. I have read about some error whan pressing the enter key here: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=17216. But that was PF 3.5 and the enter key works well for me. So I guess it's not the same issue.

Comment: @Selaron I know anyone can change HTML or even change the parameters of the submitted form. But I don't think regular users are doing it. My first guess was an older browser (such as IE 7 or 8), but in this case I know is a recent version of Chrome.

Comment: Hmm that's odd. Maybe you get feedback from that particular user(s) when they get a prominent 'invalid input' message from a validator.